# ctag ignores classes in c++

Tags: c++, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

how do you make ctags account for class in c++? when i jump to a tag of a function i get to the same name of the function but in a wrong class.

B b;
b.init();

and there are

A::init() {}
B::init() {}

i put the cursor on init of b.init() and the jump is to A::init() {} instead of B::init() {}.

Note, i didn't use a and b in my code. so this might not work if u run ctags. if it's not a common problem i ca post the actual code.

Comment: i tried "--extra=+q" as noted in http://ctags.sourceforge.net/faq.html#7. didn't help

Comment: Use visual studio. It will recognize tokens properly scoped rather than just the same word.

Comment: it won't help in any way. Vim has to understand C++ to know the type of b, and it does not.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't solve your original problem, but a mapping such as the following may help:

```
nnoremap CTRL+] :exe 'tj' expand('<cword>')<CR>
```

This will at least make `CTRL+]` show you a selection menu when there are multiple definitions of `init()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any method to do this, as it would require vim to do c++ parsing.  In that situation I use `:tselect` to show the whole list and choose one.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [lh-tags](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse#svn/tags/trunk) to solve this problem [It will require [lh-vim-lib](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhVimLib).]

It does not recognize whether b is a A or a B, but it proposes a little GUI to select which tag we want to jump to.

See it as an interactive `:tselect`. Put the cursor on an identifier and type `<c-w><m-down>` in normal mode (which is configurable). It also proposes ways to build and update the ctags base on `<c-x>ta` and on `:w` given that `g:`/`b:ctags_dirname` has been set for the current project.